# How to reliably detect a USB drive just after boot on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, raspberry-pi, udev, usb-drive

We're building a device based on Raspberry Pi. And we'd like to add an option to detect plugged USB drive on when the device boots, to e.g. perform a firmware update.

There's a problem that the USB drive is often not mountable immediately after Linux starts (and it differs between different USB drives).
Ideally I'd like a way to tell that some USB device is plugged in, as it may be worth delaying the boot procedure to let it mount, and I'd like to know how long should I wait before mounting the USB drive or giving up.

I know there's /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/delay_use parameter, but I don't know if just waiting for the time specified there would solve all my problems?
I've also looked at libudev to enumerate available devices, and add a monitor but I don't seem to get any events before the device is actually mountable.

Thanks in advance!
Piotr

Comment: If you add it ti the fstab ut shoukd work as intended.

Comment: Not quite following you... the udev rule works, but... it's bad that the device is mountable?

Comment: @frostschutz, sorry I didn't make myself clear. The problem is that I have a time window during startup of the device to perform the upgrade. And I don't see a reliable way to tell if there's a USB device plugged. udev will eventually tell me that there's a USB disk plugged in, but I don't know how long should I wait for the notification. Or should I proceed with startup of the device, as there 's most likely no device plugged in.

Comment: @user1782685 so it's a performance question, you don't want to delay the boot process? this also depends a lot on kernel configuration (when is the usb driver loaded anyway) and no matter how short you make the delay, there will be a delay, so maybe change the problem? Set a marker "check for update next boot". Then you can take your time...